# Calculate rolling avg AND rolling max for given window

Tags: python, generator

Calculate rolling avg and rolling max for given window w1.
But using is:
You should write a class which accepts an iterator and acts as a generator which yields tuples as shown above.

For example, given a stream containing the following values. W = 3.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

the following tuples would be expected, where ‘None’ indicates that a     value is not available, and would be ‘NaN’ in some languages:

```
(None, None) -- When we have input 1  --- As we dont have w num, ignore - None
(None, None) -- Now we have input 1,2 
(2, 3)       -- Now we have input 1,2,3
(3, 4)       -- Discard 1. Window [2,3,4]
(4, 5)       -- Discard 3. Window [3,4,5]
(5, 6)       -- Discard 4. Window [4,5,6]
```

In this tuple first num is avg of w (=3) numbers. And second
num is max out of w(=3) numbers.

I'm still learning iterator and generator/yield in python.

Que: So generator accepts whole sequence (or iterator/list)? What if 
the seq is huge?

I wrote simple solution which may not be effective algorithm but anyways
I want to know first if this is right with generator:

```
 7 from collections import deque
 8 class Solution:
 9     def sliding_window_avg_max(self, nums, w=3):
 10         d = deque(maxlen = w)   
 11         total = 0
 12         for n in nums:
 13             if len(d) >= w:
 14                 total = total - d.pop() + n
 15             else:
 16                 total = total + n
 17             d.append(n)
 18             if len(d) >= w:
 19                 yield (total/float(w), max(d))
 20             else:
 21                 yield(None, None)
 22 
 23 s = Solution()
 24 a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 25 for t in s.sliding_window_avg_max(a):
 26     print t
```

EDIT:
This is not homework question. This was interview question that I want
to know other's thoughts too. I really want to know how would generator help here - isnt it require list (nums) to be in memory?
And how would we use iterator if we should?

Comment: Why `(1, 2)` is not there?

Comment: ‘None’ indicates that a value is not available. Streaming data problem. When we have w = 3 values then only we calculate max/avg. Let me edit it

Comment: `tup = ((l[i], l[i+1]) for i in range(1,len(l)-1))` is a generator expr which gives you the sequence of tuples `(2,3) ... (5,6)` (just an example, I am sure it can be done better). When exactly would you require (None, None)? It's still unclear. Also: is W the length of the list?

Comment: Just edited my que. First # is avg of w. Second is max. When we dont have all w=3 numbers we dont calculate anything but return None.

Comment: the `None` case i still  very unclear to me. Aldo, can you answer the very first comment please?

Comment: `'None’ indicates that a value is not available` What value? In the `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` list? What can it be then `[None, None, 3, 4, 5, 6]`?

Comment: Edited again my example. Explaining what is my input window at each step. Let me know if now it make sense

Comment: Fro  the wording, this is very obviously homework

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is very obviously homework

Comment: Lol its not ... it was interview question and I want to know other's thoughts.

Comment: *"You should write a class which accepts an iterator and acts as a generator"* - that's not what you've written...

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks ... thats what I dont understand. What would iterator help me in here? And isnt list is iterator too (it gives next)

Comment: @codemuncher a `list` is **iterable**, but is not itself an **iterator**. *"it gives next"* - no, it doesn't; `next(some_list)` will give you `TypeError: list object is not an iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

I would divide up your approach into:

1. A generator that yields  a tuple of W numbers.  It can hold W+1 values so it know what to discard when a new number is added.
2. A calculator that calculate the mean and max for the current tuple.

There are two reasons for this.  Firstly in this context coding time is limited and it will be easier to debug the generator if you are just checking for correct delivery.  Secondly it is a more flexible approach - if the interviewer had asked to to add the minimum and standard deviation it would just be a few lines in the calculating module.

Comment: this make sense ... But what about iterator? Your (1) still requires list. I know list is iterator too but doesn't this mean we have to hold the whole list?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convert this to a class, or add it to a class as a method.

```
def sliding_window_avg_max(nums, w=3):
    if w < 1:
        raise ValueError('Window size must be > 0')
    for i in range(1, len(nums)+1):
        if i < w:
            yield None, None
        else:
            yield sum(nums[i-w:i])/float(w), max(nums[i-w:i])


>>> for t in sliding_window_avg_max([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]):
...     print t
(None, None)
(None, None)
(2.0, 3)
(3.0, 4)
(4.0, 5)
(5.0, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the specification states (emphasis mine):

> You should write a class which accepts an iterator and **acts as a
>   generator** which yields tuples as shown above.

I think you have misunderstood the question; I suspect you are being asked to implement [the iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter). One possible solution would look something like this:

```
from collections import deque


class Solution(object):
    """Apply a moving window to an iterator, calculate max and average.

    Arguments:
      iter_ (iterator): The iterator to process.
      w (int): The length of the moving window to apply.

    Attributes:
      window (deque): The moving window.

    Example:

        >>> list(Solution(range(1, 7), 3))
        [(None, None), (None, None), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]

    """

    def __init__(self, iter_, w):
        self.iter = iter(iter_)
        self.w = w
        self.window = deque(maxlen=w)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        """Calculate the next value in the series.

        Notes:
          If the window isn't full, return (None, None). 

        """
        self.window.append(next(self.iter))
        if len(self.window) == self.w:
            return self._avg(), self._max()
        return None, None

    def _max(self):
        """Calculate the maximum of the current window."""
        return max(self.window)

    def _avg(self):
        """Calculate the average of the current window."""
        return int(sum(self.window) / float(len(self.window)))
```

---

Note that you could alternatively implement `__iter__` as a generator, i.e. cut out `next` and implement:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        for val in self.iter:
            self.window.append(val)
            if len(self.window) == self.w:
                yield self._avg(), self._max()
            else:
                yield None, None
```

Either way, you're ensuring that the return from `__iter__` is an iterator!

---

The form of your solution should have given you pause; per [*"Stop Writing Classes"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0), if your class implements `__init__` and one other method (and in this case not even `__init__`!), it shouldn't be a class.

Comment: Agreed with stop writing class! ;-)  Can I convert the return to yield to make it generator? And what is iter_ in __init__ ? Can be list? Sorry for dumb question - all I am confused is iterator and generator

Comment: @codemuncher *"Can I convert the return to yield"* / *"what is iter\_ in init ? Can be list?"* - why not try them and find out (note that the latter is actually *answered in my code...*)?

Comment: thanks again, of course yield is going infinite loop: for res in s: print res.. I see in here - http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html. For generator there is some limit while i < n. So generator can store "state". 1) How would I know when to stop? And next prints generator object, why it doesn't print my tuple.

Comment: try [this excellent tutorial](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html)

Comment: @codemuncher *"And next prints generator object, why it doesn't print my tuple"* - because if you `yield` you're returning a generator object, **not a tuple**. In general, `next` (`__next__` in 3.x) should `return`, not `yield`. You *can* make `__iter__` a generator instead of implementing `next` and returning the class itself; I've added this to my answer.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I can take this iterator - next will just give next element in stream (That way I dont consume more memory) And write generator function which takes this iterator and generate rolling max/avg.

Comment: @codemuncher the current `next` *does* return the rolling maximum/average - have you actually read or tried the code?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was telling about how would I want to go. I hope you read my previous comments which mentions how would it behave if I yield it. Your solution writes iterator class but ask is to write a generator (to yield tuples) class which accepts iterator object.

Comment: @codemuncher please read the various posts I've already linked you to. A *"generator class"* is one which implements the iterator protocol. How precisely you implement it is up to you.